# HtmlCleaner failing on some xpaths generated by XPather

Tags: java, html, xpath, htmlcleaner

I am using **HtmlCleaner2.1** library for evaluating xpaths generated by **XPather** plugin against html to scrape content from it. But sometimes, HtmlCleaner fails to evaluate xpath.

For e.x.
**http://www.megaoutdoors.co.uk/norwegen-army-shirt-zipped-roll-top-collar-278-p.asp**

For product title, xpath given by XPather is **//body/div[11]/div[6]/div[2]/form/div[1]/h1**
But this fails when I evaluate it using HtmlCleaner.

How could we overcome this problem. Does structure of page change when htmlcleaner cleans it?

Thanks
Jitendra

Comment: @Jitendra: In general is not a good design choice for a document to claim XHTML validation being a not wellformed XML.

Comment: In what way does it fail? (E.g. error message, gets wrong data, gets no data ...)

Comment: @Alejandro, These websites are not ours, but we do have permission to scrape them. So we would have to scrape them in any case.

Comment: @LarsH, It fails in sense that on evaluating above xpath, It gives 0 nodes.

Comment: @Jitendra: Also do note that the DOM built by browser might be different from the DOM built by other parser (anonymous elements, mandatory TBODY, adjacents text nodes, etc.)

Comment: Alejandro, My requirement is to scrape content from html pages based on xpaths and we are using xpather plugin to generate xpaths. Is there some other html parser which is better than HtmlCleaner. It should not fail with xpather. Speed of parser is not of much concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does structure of page change when
>   htmlcleaner cleans it?

According to the intro example on http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/, HTMLCleaner **certainly can** change the structure of the page when cleaning up. In that example it adds html and body elements, and moves the h1 element out of the table.

Why don't you run HTMLCleaner on the page and look at the output from it? Then you'll be able to tell whether and how the structure has changed.

> Is there some way to avoid it or in
>   other words, keep DOM generated by
>   HtmlCleaner as close as possible to
>   DOM built by browser.

You could do this by specifying a modified tag info set, different from the [default one](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/default.xml). This is apparently what configures the "corrections" of the DOM. (See [here](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/commandlineuse.php) for how to use it, if you're using the command-line interface.)

> Or if you could suggest some another
>   html parser, whose DOM is very close
>   to DOM by browser, so that xpath
>   generated by XPather plugin would fail
>   very rarely.

I would try [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) and see what it does to the DOM. It's a widely used and mature program for tidying up scraped HTML.

Comment: Sry, Question was not framed pretty well. I was aware that structure of page changes. Is there some way to avoid it or in other words, keep DOM generated by HtmlCleaner as close as possible to DOM built by browser.

Comment: Or if you could suggest some another html parser, whose DOM is very close to DOM by browser, so that xpath generated by XPather plugin would fail very rarely.

Comment: @Jitendra, I updated my answer in response to those comments.

Comment: thnx Larsh, I would definitely try JTidy java version of Html Tidy.